# I would like to find last line on sheet2 and then be able to move each cell to a defined location on sheet1

Tags: excel, variables, cell, vba

I have searched all of the web for information shown in the subject line so I can move forward on this small project. I would like to be able to find the last row on sheet 2 and then extract the contents of each cell back to pre defined locations or pre defined variables on sheet 1.

I have been able to find the last line

```
Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
```

and populate a textbox with the contents of a defined cell

```
TextBox1.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").Value
```

I hope the above information is sufficient for someone to point me in the right direction. I appreciate and assistance that anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Workbooks("abc.xlsm").Sheets("Test_ws")

For i = 1 To 12
ws1.Cells(3, i) = ws2.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

P.S. abc.xlsm have to be open for the code to work. You may use Application.Workbooks.Open to open a file with full path.